# A valid version of XCode could not be found

Tags: xcode, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

When I open a new Xamarin-Project on Visual Studio for Mac, I instantly get the Error "A valid XCode Version could not be found."
I checked if Visual Studio has the right path to XCode.

I use XCode Version 9.4.1 since I saw that some Versions have problems

Comment: Is your Visual studio for mac updated to latest version, what is your visual studio for mac version.

Comment: Your installed version of VS4M mostly likely is an older version and does not support Xcode 9.4.x... What version do you have?